# why cant i change directories in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to change directories in python. I first tried:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
```

and got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

I then tried

```
>>> os.chir('/directory/i/want/to/change/to')
```

but I still got

```
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

How do I define the operating system?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I'd suggest reading a book on the language you're using before "diving in", it helps to avoid A LOT of pitfalls :)

Comment: Dive Into Python http://diveintopython.org/ is one of my favourite Python books

Comment: -1 for not knowing the most basic things and obviously not having read the basic tutorial

Comment: @user808545, What @Evpok refers to is that you are supposed to "accept" an answer when your question is solved. You do this by clicking the check-mark next to the answer you want to accept.

Comment: To prevent this kind of hassle, you may consider to use some alternative integrated development environment. See more for example here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments. Still, if you are asking questions and get decent answer, please don't forget to accept which suited best for you. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You need to import the os module first:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: `51 secs ago` You won by 9 seconds! Have an upvote.

Comment: @Chriszuma Thanks! It was a tough question though! :)

Comment: Wow, +10 for `import os`

Answer (score 5):

`import os`. Perhaps you should read [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Have you imported the os module?

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the package

```
import os
```